# Theorem in complex analysis.

Tags: analysis, continuity

I need hint to prove the following theorem:

> If $\mathcal f $ is continuous on $\mathbb C $  and $\mathcal f(z) = f(2z)  \forall z \in \mathbb C $ then $\mathcal f $ is constant.

Comment: You can assume that $f(z)=0$, then $f(z/2)=f(z)$ is your friend.

Comment: Compute $f(z/2^n)$ and its limit as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @quid Duplicate, indeed: asked by the same guy, with the same title and (mostly) same question.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there are two different function values $f(z_1)\neq f(z_2)$. What can you say about $f(z_1/2)$ and $f(z_2/2)$? Repeat this $n$ times, say, and you can see why there must be a discontinuity at $0$.

Comment: In fact, this is not a complex analysis fact :)